# mysql: If a value appears more than once, get values from the others similar rows and create new columns

Tags: mysql

Here is an example of my table patients:

```
 id  |   case_id   | patient_id   | syndrome |  age |
------------------------------------------------------
  1  |    23       |      24      | stable   |  45  |
  2  |    24       |      25      | stable   |  64  |
  3  |    25       |      24      | coronary |  46  |
  4  |    26       |      27      | stable   |  73  |
  5  |    27       |      24      | stable   |  48  |
  6  |    28       |      25      | coronary |  67  |
  7  |    29       |      40      | coronary |  68  |
```

If patient_id appears more than once, i only want to show the first row and add extra columns to this row containing the values of the others similar patient_ids.

For example

```
 id  |   case_id   | patient_id   | syndrome |  age | syndrome2  | age2 | syndrome3  | age3 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  1  |    23       |      24      | stable   |  45  | coronary   |   46 |  stable    | 48
  2  |    24       |      25      | stable   |  64  | coronary   |   67 |            |
  7  |    29       |      40      | coronary |  68  |
```

Is this feasible using mysql code?

Currently, I have this code:

```
  SELECT *, count(patients.patient_id) as PatientsNo  FROM patients
                GROUP BY patient_id 
                HAVING COUNT(patient_id) > 1
```

Any suggestions please?

Thank you in advance,
Zinon

Comment: Don't try to dynamically generate columns in SQL.  MySQL has the `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function, which will create comma-separated lists of the multiple values, which you can much more easily separate and deal with in your application code.  Ex:  `SELECT patient_id, GROUP_CONCAT(syndrome), GROUP_CONCAT(age) FROM patients GROUP BY patient_id`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Since I want futher process, it will help me to have extra columns, not one having comma separated values.

Comment: Ok, but SQL is not good at that sort of thing.  You can perform complex left joins to get one row at a time when multiples exist, but you can't do it indeterministically. That is, you have to know ahead of time how many you need to get. At that point you will be writing dynamic SQL to execute by the RDBMS, which is way harder than just unraveling the delimited values application-side.